# Using a for loop Windows batch executes twice

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I'm trying to loop through folders and files in order to command on all of them.

```
for /d %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

However the folder appears to be listed twice:

```
echo test
test
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You're not seeing the folder twice, you're seeing the command `echo test` happening and then the result of the command - `test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable displaying of the commands before execution:

- add `@echo off` as the first line of the batch file
- or prefix the command with `@`, for example: `@echo %%i`